# Create 2D array from 1D array in Rust

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, rust

I have two `2D` arrays in `Rust` like this

```
    let d1: [[T; 3]; 3] = ...
    let d2: [[T; 3]; 3] = ...
```

Now I want to add the elements `element-wise` and assign the result to a new `2D` array.

My current solution looks like this:

```
    let mut result = [[T::default(); ROW]; COL];
    
    for (i, row) in d1.iter().enumerate() {
        for (j, element) in row.iter().enumerate() {
            result[i][j] = *element + d2[i][j];
        }
    }
```

This is inefficient as it first fills `result` with default values only to override them later.

Therefore I want to solve this using iterators by flattening the `2D` arrays and then adding the elements.

However, I don't know how I can construct a `2D` array from the resulting flattened `1D` iterator :

```
    let result = for sum in d1.iter().flatten().zip(
                            d2.iter().flatten())
                            .map(|(x, y)| x+y)
                            .collect().???
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked that it indeed makes a difference?

Comment: As I don't have a solution for the second approach, I can't benchmark it yet. I will when I have both approaches implemented. But I think, it is a valid question regardless of the performance.

Comment: This is surely a valid question out of curiousity, but if you actually want to use it I'd recommend you to benchmark. As for how to benchmark, you can us3 `MaybeUninit` to avoid the initialization overhead.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently learning Rust and decided to implement a simple Matrix class to learn in practice. I will definitely try benchmarking with `MaybeUninit`, haven't heard of it yet. Thank you!

Comment: Note that all of this runs on the stack, so you will run into stack overflows pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a hybrid approach.

You can initialize a fixed-size array via first constructing a `[(); N]` and then calling `.map()` on it. Combined with iterators over the input arrays, this should be somewhat performant.

Although I still recommend benchmarking it vs the naive solution.

```rust
fn add_2d<'a, 'b, T, const W: usize, const H: usize>(
    d1: &'a [[T; W]; H],
    d2: &'b [[T; W]; H],
) -> [[T; W]; H]
where
    T: 'static,
    &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    let mut iter_row = d1.iter().zip(d2.iter());

    [(); H].map(move |()| {
        let (row1, row2) = iter_row.next().unwrap();
        let mut elem_iter = row1.iter().zip(row2.iter());
        [(); W].map(move |()| {
            let (elem1, elem2) = elem_iter.next().unwrap();
            elem1 + elem2
        })
    })
}

fn main() {
    let d1: [[u32; 2]; 3] = [[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]];
    let d2: [[u32; 2]; 3] = [[10, 20], [40, 50], [70, 80]];

    let sums = add_2d(&d1, &d2);
    println!("{:?}", sums);
}
```

```
[[11, 22], [44, 55], [77, 88]]
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind `unsafe`, this is what I would probably go for to achieve maximum performance:

```rust
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

fn add_2d<'a, 'b, T, const W: usize, const H: usize>(
    d1: &'a [[T; W]; H],
    d2: &'b [[T; W]; H],
) -> [[T; W]; H]
where
    T: 'static,
    &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    let mut result: MaybeUninit<[[T; W]; H]> = MaybeUninit::uninit();

    let arr_ptr = result.as_mut_ptr() as *mut [T; W];

    unsafe {
        for y in 0..H {
            let row_ptr = arr_ptr.add(y) as *mut T;
            let row1 = d1.get_unchecked(y);
            let row2 = d2.get_unchecked(y);
            for x in 0..W {
                row_ptr
                    .add(x)
                    .write(row1.get_unchecked(x) + row2.get_unchecked(x));
            }
        }

        result.assume_init()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let d1: [[u32; 2]; 3] = [[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]];
    let d2: [[u32; 2]; 3] = [[10, 20], [40, 50], [70, 80]];

    let sums = add_2d(&d1, &d2);
    println!("{:?}", sums);
}
```

```
[[11, 22], [44, 55], [77, 88]]
```

Be sure to use `.write()` instead of a simple assignment operation, because the assignment operation would run the `Drop` function of the previous, uninitialized element. Which would cause undefined behaviour.

---

### Benchmarks

I added `hkBst`'s `.map().collect().try_into().unwrap()` based method to the benchmarks, as well:

```rust
#![feature(bench_black_box)]

use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

fn add_2d_iter<'a, 'b, T, const W: usize, const H: usize>(
    d1: &'a [[T; W]; H],
    d2: &'b [[T; W]; H],
) -> [[T; W]; H]
where
    T: 'static,
    &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    let mut iter_row = d1.iter().zip(d2.iter());

    [(); H].map(move |()| {
        let (row1, row2) = iter_row.next().unwrap();
        let mut elem_iter = row1.iter().zip(row2.iter());
        [(); W].map(move |()| {
            let (elem1, elem2) = elem_iter.next().unwrap();
            elem1 + elem2
        })
    })
}

fn add_2d_uninit<'a, 'b, T, const W: usize, const H: usize>(
    d1: &'a [[T; W]; H],
    d2: &'b [[T; W]; H],
) -> [[T; W]; H]
where
    T: 'static,
    &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    let mut result: MaybeUninit<[[T; W]; H]> = MaybeUninit::uninit();

    let arr_ptr = result.as_mut_ptr() as *mut [T; W];

    unsafe {
        for y in 0..H {
            let row_ptr = arr_ptr.add(y) as *mut T;
            let row1 = d1.get_unchecked(y);
            let row2 = d2.get_unchecked(y);
            for x in 0..W {
                row_ptr
                    .add(x)
                    .write(row1.get_unchecked(x) + row2.get_unchecked(x));
            }
        }

        result.assume_init()
    }
}

fn add_2d_unwrap<'a, 'b, T, const W: usize, const H: usize>(
    a: &'a [[T; W]; H],
    b: &'b [[T; W]; H],
) -> [[T; W]; H]
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug + 'static,
    &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    a.iter()
        .zip(b.iter())
        .map(|(ai, bi)| {
            ai.iter()
                .zip(bi.iter())
                .map(|(aij, bij)| aij + bij)
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                .try_into()
                .unwrap()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .try_into()
        .unwrap()
}

const W: usize = 30;
const H: usize = 30;
const ITERATIONS: usize = 1000000;

fn check_result(d1: &[[i32; W]; H], d2: &[[i32; W]; H], result: &[[i32; W]; H]) -> bool {
    for y in 0..H {
        for x in 0..W {
            if d1[y][x] + d2[y][x] != result[y][x] {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    true
}

fn bench<'a, 'b>(
    a: &'a [[i32; W]; H],
    b: &'b [[i32; W]; H],
    function: fn(&'a [[i32; W]; H], &'b [[i32; W]; H]) -> [[i32; W]; H],
) -> Vec<u128> {
    // Assert correctness and cache warmup
    {
        let sums = function(a, b);
        assert!(check_result(a, b, &sums));
        std::hint::black_box(sums);
    }

    // Bench runs
    (0..5)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|_| {
            let t0 = std::time::Instant::now();
            for _ in 0..ITERATIONS {
                std::hint::black_box(function(a, b));
            }
            t0.elapsed().as_micros()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}

fn main() {
    let mut num_iter = (1..).into_iter();
    let mut init_arr = move || [(); H].map(|()| [(); W].map(|()| num_iter.next().unwrap()));

    let d1 = init_arr();
    let d2 = init_arr();

    let times_iter = bench(&d1, &d2, add_2d_iter);
    let times_uninit = bench(&d1, &d2, add_2d_uninit);
    let times_unwrap = bench(&d1, &d2, add_2d_unwrap);

    println!("iter: {:?}", times_iter);
    println!("uninit: {:?}", times_uninit);
    println!("unwrap: {:?}", times_unwrap);
}
```

```
> cargo +nightly run --release
iter: [223519, 207772, 208043, 208497, 208807]
uninit: [202719, 202888, 201159, 202685, 201941]
unwrap: [864150, 866233, 863023, 859486, 852098]
```

Seems like `unwrap` is a bit slower, while the other two don't really make a difference.

Comment: For me it seems that the "naive" implementation is the fastest, but requires the `Default` trait. The results are:

```naive: [402429, 401400, 401249, 400432, 400355]```

```iter: [749904, 747838, 748133, 747185, 748023]```

```uninit: [424482, 421838, 421431, 421345, 421134]```

```unwrap: [3491545, 3465526, 3555841, 3514036, 3461563]```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 1):

This code adds a 2D array without initializing it with default elements, but it does go through a Vec to array conversion, because you cannot collect directly into an array. I estimate the likelihood of this being optimized away to be much lower than for your default elements solution.

```rust
fn add_3by3(a: [[u32; 3]; 3], b: [[u32; 3]; 3]) -> [[u32; 3]; 3] {
    a.iter()
        .zip(b.iter())
        .map(|(ai, bi)| {
            ai.iter()
                .zip(bi.iter())
                .map(|(aij, bij)| aij + bij)
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                .try_into()
                .unwrap()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .try_into()
        .unwrap()
}
```

Incidentally, I think it is probably a better idea to keep your data in a 1D array no matter what actual shape it has, and keep shape information on the side. That way every element-wise operation is very simple.